# How to extract the methods of the a nested object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How do I access the getter methods of a nested custom object? I am able to extract the methods which return Strings but not able to extract methods of a nested object.

My implementation is as follows:

```
public class DataExtraction {

    public void showTheData(Object student) throws IOException {

        Class classofStudent = student.getClass();

        Method[] methodsOfStudent = classofStudent.getDeclaredMethods();


        for(Method method:methodsOfStudent) 
        {

            if(isGetType(method)) 
            {
                if(method.getReturnType()==String.class) 
                {
                    try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("ObjectFileReaderPrimitive.properties"))
                    {
                        //InputStream is = new FileInputStream("ObjectFileReaderPrimitive.properties");
                        Properties properties = new Properties();
                        properties.load(is);
                    System.out.println(properties.getProperty(method.getName()));   

                    }
                }
             else 

                try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream("ObjectFileReaderNonPrimitive.properties"))
                {
                    Class innerObjectClass = method.getReturnType().getClass();
                    Method[] methodsOfinnerObject = innerObjectClass.getDeclaredMethods();
                    for(Method methodofInnerClass : methodsOfinnerObject) {
                        if(isGetType(method)) 
                        {
                            Properties properties = new Properties();
                            properties.load(is);
                            System.out.println(properties.getProperty(methodofInnerClass.getName()));   
                        }
                }}
            }
        }}

    private boolean isGetType(Method method) {

        if(method.getName().startsWith("get"))

        return true;
        return false;
    }


}
```

Where the student class is as follows-:

```
package com.sample;

public class Student {

    private String id;
    private String section;
    private Address address;
    public Student(String id, String section, Address address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.section = section;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Student() {
        super();
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }
    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", section=" + section + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }



}
```

Address Object-:

```
package com.sample;

public class Address {


    private String AddressLine1;
    private String AddressLine2;
    private String AddressLine3;
    public Address(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String addressLine3) {
        super();
        AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
        AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
        AddressLine3 = addressLine3;
    }
    public Address() {
        super();
    }
    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return AddressLine1;
    }
    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        AddressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }
    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return AddressLine2;
    }
    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        AddressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }
    public String getAddressLine3() {
        return AddressLine3;
    }
    public void setAddressLine3(String addressLine3) {
        AddressLine3 = addressLine3;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address [AddressLine1=" + AddressLine1 + ", AddressLine2=" + AddressLine2 + ", AddressLine3="
                + AddressLine3 + "]";
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you show the Address object too.

Comment: Hi @Dean..Added the Address Object.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a modified version of your code that prints all getter methods in Student and Object. If your code is still not working it is for a different reason.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not actually getting the correct class for your inner custom object.

Currently you are doing:

```
Class innerObjectClass = method.getReturnType().getClass();
```

This does not work because the method `getReturnType` is already returning the `Class` object of the return type. So what is happening is you are calling `getClass()` on a class object. This will return `class java.lang.Class`. You just need to remove the call to getClass:

```
Class innerObjectClass = method.getReturnType();
```

Here I have modified your code so that it prints all the getter objects in `Student` and `Address`

```
 Class classofStudent = Student.class;
    Method[] methodsOfStudent = classofStudent.getDeclaredMethods();

    for (Method method : methodsOfStudent) {

        if (isGetType(method)) {
            if (method.getReturnType() == String.class) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
            } else {

                Class innerObjectClass = method.getReturnType();
                Method[] methodsOfinnerObject = innerObjectClass.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (Method methodofInnerClass : methodsOfinnerObject) {
                    if (isGetType(method)) {
                        System.out.println(methodofInnerClass.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Dean, This is working ...Thanks for your response ..Can you please tell me how do i fetch the value of the fields of the same address class...?

Comment: Please submit a separate question and link it.